# Weird Behavior of Xcode when debugging on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, debugging

I have an app that i'm developing for a quit long time now, and is already in the appstore.

I'm currently working on updates to this app, and when i'm testing it on the device i'm experiencing a weird behavior:
Every time i'm trying to install and debug the app from xcode, the app start running, but after 10 seconds or so the app is crashing with no reason.

The weirdest thing is that when i'm re-running the app directly from the device, everything work just fine without any crashes.

Needless to say that in the simulator everything is working as expected.

Any suggestions what is going on?

Comment: Do you get any debugger messages?

Comment: Which version of Xcode? Have you tried debugging with different versions (3 and 4)?

Comment: Not exactly: when the app crashes on the device, the debugger says: "Error from debugger - The program being debugged is not being run". Which is pretty obvious and not helping...

Comment: @James Bedford - I'm using Xcode 3, and didn't try yet on the Xcode 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check whether your using the Distribution certificate for debugging. If its then change into development certificate for Debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Your app may be taking too long to start when attached to the debugger. Remember that on iOS every app must go through applicationDidFinishLaunching in less than 20 seconds, otherwise it's killed by the OS.

In your case I would review the workload that is going into the applicationDidFinishLaunching method of your app delegate (or any other static initialization of objects occurring before that). Also make sure you aren't running network checks whose timeout may exceed that 20 seconds window (e.g. don't do reachability tests).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but this is obviously not the case:
1. My app is up and running in very short time. it crashes while it is fully loaded and reactive.
2. This should be applied also to the case where i'm running the app directly from the springboard - but when i do that everything is working fine.